# System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out Even I am Doing DML after callout

Tags: apex, api, batch, callout, queueable-apex

******************Description******************
I am getting huge 30 mb csv data in chunks via api from aws and passing these chunks in Queueable Class that is called from same api class. Queueable Class is further calling batch apex with batch size 1. DML operation is after callout but i am stuck.

***END***

***Queueable Apex***

```
public ESGGetCompanyAnalyticsServiceAWSQueable(list<ESGGetCompanyAnalyticsServiceAWS.ESGCompanyFieldsWrapper> recs) {
      this.ESGCompanyFieldsWrapperLst=recs;
      recs= new list<ESGGetCompanyAnalyticsServiceAWS.ESGCompanyFieldsWrapper>(); 
      system.debug('proco__ESG_Company__c DataQ>>>>>>' + this.ESGCompanyFieldsWrapperLst);
  }
  
  public  void execute(QueueableContext queCont) {
        list<ESGGetCompanyAnalyticsServiceAWS.ESGCompanyFieldsWrapper> ESGCompanyFieldsWrapperLst1=this.ESGCompanyFieldsWrapperLst;
      if(this.ESGCompanyFieldsWrapperLst !=Null)
      {
    system.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>'+this.ESGCompanyFieldsWrapperLst);
    this.ESGCompanyFieldsWrapperLst= new list<ESGGetCompanyAnalyticsServiceAWS.ESGCompanyFieldsWrapper>();
      ESGGetCompanyAnalyticsServiceAWSBatch zib = new ESGGetCompanyAnalyticsServiceAWSBatch(this.ESGCompanyFieldsWrapperLst); 
      Id jobId= database.executeBatch(zib,10);
      
      ESGCompanyFieldsWrapperLst1= new list<ESGGetCompanyAnalyticsServiceAWS.ESGCompanyFieldsWrapper>();
    this.ESGCompanyFieldsWrapperLst= new list<ESGGetCompanyAnalyticsServiceAWS.ESGCompanyFieldsWrapper>();
}
```

**END**

**METHOD Calling API AND QUEUEABLE CLASS**

```
public static String saveFile() {
            //csv=null;
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpRequest req= createHttpRequest();
            HttpResponse response = http.send(req);
            String responseBody= response.getBody();
            list<String> columnValues = new list<String>();
            list<String> filelines =responseBody.split('\n');
            system.debug('Debug filelinesESGCompanyFieldsWrapperLstESGCompanyFieldsWrapperLst>>>  filelines.add(string.valueOf(r)'+filelines);
            transient list<ESGCompanyFieldsWrapper> ESGCompanyFieldsWrapperLst= new list<ESGCompanyFieldsWrapper>();            
            system.debug('Debug filelinesESGCompanyFieldsWrapperLstESGCompanyFieldsWrapperLst>>>');
            if(filelines.size()>0)
            {

            for (Integer j=0;j<filelines.size();j++)
            {
                system.debug('insidefor>>');
            columnValues = filelines[j].split(',');
            ESGCompanyFieldsWrapper esg= new ESGCompanyFieldsWrapper();
            esg.ESG_Company_Id = columnValues[0];
            esg.Prospect_Company_Name = columnValues[1];
            esg.Air_Quality_avg = columnValues[2];
            esg.Access_and_Affordability ='0';// columnValues[3];
            esg.Access_and_Affordability_avg ='0';// columnValues[4];
            esg.Air_Quality = columnValues[5];
            esg.Business_Ethics = columnValues[6];
            esg.Business_Ethics_avg = columnValues[7];
            esg.Business_Model_Resilience = columnValues[8];
            esg.Business_Model_Resilience_avg = columnValues[9];
            esg.Competitive_Behavior = columnValues[10];
            esg.Competitive_Behavior_avg = columnValues[11];
            esg.Critical_Incident_Risk_Management = columnValues[12];
            esg.Critical_Incident_Risk_Management_avg = columnValues[13];
            esg.Customer_Privacy = columnValues[14];
            esg.Customer_Privacy_avg = columnValues[15];
            esg.Customer_Welfare = columnValues[16];
            esg.Customer_Welfare_avg =0;//columnValues[17];
            esg.Data_Security = 0;//columnValues[18];//columnValues[18];
            esg.Data_Security_avg =0;// columnValues[19];
            esg.Ecological_Impacts = 0;//columnValues[20];
            esg.Ecological_Impacts_avg = 0;//columnValues[21];
            esg.Employee_Engagement_Diversity_AND_In_avg =0;// columnValues[22];
            esg.Employee_Engagement_Diversity_And_Incl =0;// columnValues[23];
            esg.Employee_Health_And_Safety = 0;//columnValues[24];
            esg.Employee_Health_And_Safety_avg =0;// columnValues[25];
            ESGCompanyFieldsWrapperLst.add(esg);
                 
            }
                }
               system.debug('Debug outside for ESGCompanyFieldsWrapperLst>>'+ESGCompanyFieldsWrapperLst.size());
               
               ID jobID =  System.enqueuejob(new ESGGetCompanyAnalyticsServiceAWSQueable(ESGCompanyFieldsWrapperLst));

               filelines=new List<string>();
               ESGCompanyFieldsWrapperLst= new List<ESGCompanyFieldsWrapper>();
    return 'success';
}
```

**END**

Comment: Can you paste the full code, I dont see any DML in above code

Comment: DML is in batch that is being called from queueable class

Comment: And where is callout happening?

Comment: First Code is for callout as you can see

Comment: Please share the full code from where the api is being fired and how that is connected to Queueable and Batch class.

Comment: @NagendraSingh  i have updated question please see

Comment: Where is saveFile being called, you may have to paste that file too. We need to understand the connection between classes.

Comment: getting error when i call savefile from anonymous window

Answer (score 0):

By viewing your code it is not possible to face the error `System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out`

Here are two scenarios where **this exception comes**  and check what is actually happening.

1. Calling a Queueable or future before callout. (This also gets considered as DML before callout)
2. Doing a DML (insert, update, upsert, delete) before callout.

Please check if either of these combinations are in your code.